# How can one disclaim?

Tags: journals, plagiarism, online-publication

How can an innocent person disclaim a plagiarized publication which he did not give consent for publication?
The paper has has been published without my consent and my name was included as a co-author but i want to disassociate myself from this paper?

Comment: Was a paper containing plagiarism published with your name on it or is it plagiarized because you did not approve of the publication?

Comment: the paper containing plagiarism was published with my name. I saw it on researchgate.

Answer (score 10):

If this is a published with some legitimate publisher, then contacting the publisher and pointing out that you never consented to being named as an author on that paper should suffice. The publication record should be amended, and the paper probably be withdrawn.

If this is not published with a legitimate publisher, the strategy above might fail. You can try to threaten to sue them, but ultimately the most you can reliably do is to put a disclaimer on your homepage.

This could take a form like "It has come to my attention that the publication XXX lists me as a coauthor. I have not been involved in this project / not consented to the final form (pick as appropriate). The publisher YYY has been informed of this on DATE and is yet to take action. (you should probably give the publisher a few weeks to react before putting this up).

Comment: thank. What exactly can be in the content of such disclaimer? The paper is already on researchgate and i never gave the lead author consent to include my name or even the Publisher to publish. What do I do?

Comment: Contact ResearchGate. They seem to be trying to become legitimate source for scientists, so they should take your complaint VERY seriously.

Comment: @xmp125a Assuming that ResearchGate is just reporting that the paper has been published elsewhere, then I think elsewhere is the first point of contact.

Comment: @Arno if the journal/conference in question is obscure and uncooperative, at least he can remove it from one of the sources where it seems to reach large audience (since OP discovered it this way).